# App build fails by Push-Plugin - Cordova 5.3.3 Android Eclipse

Tags: android, cordova

I created an cordova-app, added the push-plugin (github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and also added the quick-example code.

But when i want to emulate the app in eclipse it fails with "unfortunately app has stopped".
I found out that the problem is the push-plugin. I´m guessing it cannot register?!

Logcat/DDMS says this (screenshot):
[image: screenshot]

Is there a class missing (looks like something went wrong with class "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID")? How can I fix this?

Can someone please help me?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

It is `class not found exception` , maybe you miss a jar in your app , please check jar in `libs`  and your project if you have referenced the `jar` or `library` .

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply! i added the google-play-services like this (adding as library): http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-1igxw4.png and the support-libraries like this (adding to build path): http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-22wlit.png do i have to set something in the AndroidManifest maybe? the app crashes as soon as var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "XXXX"},
         "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } ); is called

Comment: okay, guess i got it. i checked the checkbox in order and export and the app isn´t failing any more now :) -> http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-1fluao.png :) but now i get the following error "Empty registration ID received from GCM".. someone knows why? or is this just because of the emulator?

Comment: okay you need a real device with google play! on my smartphone it works perfectly! thanks!

Comment: Your emulator doesn't contain a Google  play service, you need to test on a real phone , congratulations ,you have solved the problem!